# strftime hour format %H returns 00 no matter the hour

Tags: python

Following this simple function

```
def get_yyyy_mm_dd_hh():
    return date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d#%H')

print(
    get_yyyy_mm_dd_hh()
)
```

I keep getting hour to `00` no matter what. Example output:

```
2021-08-12#00
```

I have tested on different unix machines, online python compilers as well as my local PC, whereas the current hour is *13* or *1PM*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `today()` returns `date` object which defaults the time to `00:00:00`. You probably need `now()` that'll return current time (`datetime` object):

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_yyyy_mm_dd_hh():
    return datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d#%H')

print(
    get_yyyy_mm_dd_hh()
)
```

Comment: Thank you, however this throws AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'now'

Comment: @Constantin it should be `import datetime; datetime.datetime.now()`.